# Configuring django 1.8.4, python 2.76, wsgi, and apache2

Tags: python, django, apache, debian

I have my site working with:

```
python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.128:8000
```

I am now trying to deploy it with wsgi.
I believe that wsgi is installed correctly (it resides in /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so)

I have set up the following settings files:

settings.py:

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'I have no idea if this needs to be secret :-)'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
# This is over-ridden in settings-production
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
ADMINS = (
    ('test', 'test@thompco.com'),
)

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'tester',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
  'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
  'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
  'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'tester.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
  {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': ['templates'],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
      'context_processors': [
        'django.template.context_processors.debug',
        'django.template.context_processors.request',
        'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
        'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
      ],
    },
  },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'tester.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
# These values are over-ridden in settings-private
try:
  from settings_private import *
except:
  DATABASES = {
    'default': {
      'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
      'NAME':     'DATABASE_NAME',
      'USER':     'USER_NAME',
      'PASSWORD': 'USER_PASSWORD',
      'HOST':     'localhost',
      'PORT':     '3306',
    }
  }

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

settings_production.py:

```
from settings import *

# Need the following to secure the final website (good candidate for a settings.production)
DEBUG = False
SECURE_CONTENT_TYPE_NOSNIFF =  True
SECURE_HSTS_SECONDS = 60
SECURE_HSTS_INCLUDE_SUBDOMAINS = True
SECURE_BROWSER_XSS_FILTER = True
SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = "DENY"
```

settings_private.py:

```
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
DATABASES = {
  'default': {
    'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME':     'mydatabase',
    'USER':     'myuser',
    'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
    'HOST':     'localhost',
    'PORT':     '3306',
  }
}
```

If I run:

```
python manage.py check --deploy --settings=settings_production
```

I get:

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
```

So I think that at least the django stuff is ready to go.  Now on to apache.  Here is where I am lost.

my django app resides in /home/jordan/django/tester (this is where the django files are that I am working on.)

I have tried to add the following to my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:

```
Alias /static/ /home/jordan/django/tester/static

<Directory /home/jordan/django/tester/static>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jordan/django/tester.wsgi

<Directory /home/jordan/django/tester>
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I added the following to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf in the  section:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess tester
WSGIProcessGroup tester
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jordan/django/tester/wsgi.py
```

I then do:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

And navigate to localhost/tester and get a 403 Forbidden page.

I am pretty sure I am missing something (probably a whole lot!) in the apache configuration files.  Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Your `sites-enabled/000-default.conf` should look like this:

```
WSGIDaemonProcess tester python-path=/home/jordan/django:/path/to/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup tester
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/jordan/django/tester/wsgi.py


<Directory /home/jordan/django/tester>
  <Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
  </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /home/jordan/django/tester/static

<Directory /home/jordan/django/tester/static>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

If you're using apache older than 2.4, replace `Require all granted` with 2 lines:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```

Also replace `/path/to/venv/` in WSGIDaemonProcess with path to your virtualenv. If not using virtualenv, leave only path to you django project here (remove path to virtualenv and colon).

`apache2.conf` should be left as default, so remove anything you've added into it.

Comment: thanks for you help GwnBleidD.  I am not using any virtual environments, do I need to set my WSGIDaemonProcess any differently?

Comment: Also, where do I browse to?  I am assuming http://localhost/tester/admin should work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there were multiple problems.  GwynBleidD solved most of them, but I was missing the final piece to the puzzle:

the wsgi.py file should read:

```
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and **NOT**

```
import django.core.handlers.wsgi
application = django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```